# Handling special letters in MySQL in Objective-C

Tags: mysql, objective-c, special-characters

I retrieve names from the database and store their first and last name in an NSMutableDictionary and store those in an NSMutableArray. In the database I have names that have special characters, such as 
'ñ', 'Ç' and of sorts and when I store the name in a variable, it stores , which crashes my program.

I don't want to restrict the user input, so I have to keep these characters. But is there a work around to retrieving these names with such characters without getting  for output?

`ConDAO *con = [[ConDAO alloc] init];`

`NSMutableArray *resultSet =  [con executeMySqlCommand:[NSString stringWithFormat:(Long query here)]];`

`NSMutableDictionary * endList = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [endList setObject: @"" forKey:@"surname"];
    [endList setObject: @"" forKey:@"name"];`

`resultSet =(NSMutableArray *)[resultSet arrayByAddingObject:endList];`

```
for (int i =0; i< [resultSet  count]-1; ++i)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *temp = (NSMutableDictionary *) [resultSet objectAtIndex:i];

...
}

-(NSMutableArray *) executeMySqlCommand: (NSString *) mysqlCommand{
    LoginData* loginData=[self dataObject]; 
    NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@&mysqlCommand=%@",
                     loginData.loginName, loginData.loginPassword, mysqlCommand ];
   NSString *hostStr = @myIP;

    hostStr = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:post];
    NSString *encodeURL =[hostStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: encodeURL ]];    

    NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    if ([serverOutput length]<=0) return nil;
    NSError * error;
    NSMutableArray *data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataURL options:0 error:&error];
    return data;
}
```

Comment: How do you store the strings, using `NSString`?

Comment: [currentStudent setObject:[temp objectForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"name"]; Where temp is a row of a Select Query.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.  What class is returned from `[temp objectForKey:@"name"]`?

Comment: `i< [resultSet  count]-1` looks suspicious.  Also it looks like you've exposed your database access via a web server?  That can't be a good idea...

Comment: Why? It is an array, so [count] is a legit method to call to iterate through the query.

Comment: No, you are missing the last result.  You need `i < [resultSet count]` instead.

Comment: That wasn't the question, in the ... I handle the last case.

Comment: True.  I suspect it's an encoding issue.  Are you sure `NSASCIIStringEncoding` is correct?

Comment: I think that could be an issue. What could I put there? There seems to be a lot of options.

Comment: You need to know what the web server is returning and mysql as well.  There could be a problem at the server end as well.  Use a MySQL client library, instead of this web server lash-up, and these problems will disappear I suspect.

Comment: Can you put it as an answer with a bit more explanation, because I have no idea what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually a problem of using the .php. The encoding that was used did not cover the special characters, so I had to use UTF8 encoding inside the .php when it makes the DB call.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using a strange server architecture where your queries are going to the database via a web server.  You are assuming that the strings being returned are encoded as ASCII, as shown here:

```
NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL
                                               encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

and it's clear you don't know what the correct encoding should be.  Your strange server architecture is further complicating matters as there could be encoding issues between the web server and database itself.

The correct solution to this problem is to use a MySQL client library to perform your queries as converting between different storage and presentation text encodings is bread and butter for any database.

You don't say whether you are working with iOS or OSX;

If OSX then you can probably install something from [macports](http://macports.org):

- [MySQL 5.5](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/databases/mysql55/Portfile) Then access the official C API in libmysqlclient.
- [mysql55-connector-cpp](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/databases/mysql55-connector-cpp/Portfile) Which looks like a C++ wrapper that doesn't require MySQL to be installed (it does depend on boost however so might be no quicker to build).

If iOS then this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924271/has-anyone-compared-iphone-mysql-clients) probably covers it.